# Using '__progname' instead of argv[0]

Tags: c, unix

In the C / Unix environment I work in, I see some developers using `__progname` instead of `argv[0]` for usage messages. Is there some advantage to this? What's the difference between `__progname` and `argv[0]`.  Is it portable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`__progname` isn't standard and therefore not portable, prefer `argv[0]`. I suppose `__progname` could lookup a string resource to get the name which isn't dependent on the filename you ran it as. But `argv[0]` will give you the name they *actually* ran it as which I would find more useful.

Comment: Consider: execl("/bin/sh", "hot potatoes", "-c", "echo $0 - Hi", (char *)0);  Works fine; argv[0] is "hot potatoes"; echoes "hot potatoes - Hi".  That's nothing to do with the name of the executable that was run.

Comment: Despite the previous comment - I agree that argv[0] is more portable.  And only a few programs mess with argv[0] like that - but any attacker can do so.  Be cautious about basing critical decisions on argv[0].

Answer (score 9):

Using `__progname` allows you to alter the contents of the `argv[]` array while still maintaining the program name.  Some of the common tools such as `getopt()` modify `argv[]` as they process the arguments.

For portability, you can `strcopy argv[0]` into your own `progname` buffer when your program starts.

Comment: GNU getopt() messes with argv; non-GNU versions do not generally do so.

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, thanks for the clarification.  I GNU I'd been sticking with one platform for too long.  (Sorry.)

Answer (score 6):

There is also a GNU extension for this, so that one can access the program invocation name from outside of main() without saving it manually. One might be better off doing it manually, however; thus making it portable as opposed to relying on the GNU extension. Nevertheless, I here provide an excerpt from the available documentation.

From [the on-line GNU C Library manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html#Error-Messages) (accessed today):

"Many programs that don't read input from the terminal are designed to exit if any system call fails. By convention, the error message from such a program should start with the program's name, sans directories. You can find that name in the variable `program_invocation_short_name`; the full file name is stored the variable `program_invocation_name`.

- Variable: char * **program_invocation_name**
  This variable's value is the name that was used to invoke the program running in the current process. It is the same as `argv[0]`. Note that this is not necessarily a useful file name; often it contains no directory names.
- Variable: char * **program_invocation_short_name**
  This variable's value is the name that was used to invoke the program running in the current process, with directory names removed. (That is to say, it is the same as `program_invocation_name` minus everything up to the last slash, if any.)

The library initialization code sets up both of these variables before calling main.

**Portability Note:** These two variables are GNU extensions. If you want your program to work with non-GNU libraries, you must save the value of `argv[0]` in main, and then strip off the directory names yourself. We added these extensions to make it possible to write self-contained error-reporting subroutines that require no explicit cooperation from main."

Answer (score 5):

I see at least two potential problems with argv[0].

First, argv[0] or argv itself may be NULL if execve() caller was evil or careless enough. Calling execve("foobar", NULL, NULL) is usually an easy and fun way to prove an over confident programmer his code is not sig11-proof.

It must also be noted that argv will not be defined outside of main() while __progname is usually defined as a global variable you can use from within your usage() function or even before main() is called (like non standard GCC constructors).

Comment: But "a Strictly Conforming POSIX Application to pass at least one argument to the exec function, thus guaranteeing that argc be one or greater when invoked by such an application." Surely no one would knowingly violate POSIX! (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exec.html)

Answer (score 4):

It's a BSDism, and definitely not portable.

Answer (score 2):

__progname is just argv[0], and examples in other replies here show the weaknesses of using it. Although not portable either, I'm using readlink on /proc/self/exe (Linux, Android), and reading the contents of /proc/self/exefile (QNX).

Comment: Since /proc can find the correct exacutable path, there must be some system funciton for it.

Answer (score 1):

If your program was run using, for instance, a symbolic link, argv[0] will contain the name of that link.

I'm guessing that __progname will contain the name of the actual program file.

In any case, argv[0] is defined by the C standard. __progname is not.