# Boost.Filesystem how to find out in which directory your executable is?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

So I run my app. I need for it to know where its executable is. How to find path to it using Boost.Filesystem?

Comment: Do you mean the *current working directory* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), or the actual directory where the executable lives?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with boost::filesystem

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/933850/240633 for alternative solutions

Answer (score -34, accepted):

If you mean from inside the executable that you're running, you can use [boost::filesystem::current_path()](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#current_path)

Comment: This will not work if the program directory is different from the current working directory. For example, consider a program started from the shell in this manner: `./foo/program`.

Comment: great example of how bad answers become accepted on the site

Answer (score 38):

```
boost::filesystem::system_complete(argv[0]);
```

e.g.

```
[davka@bagvapp Debug]$ ./boostfstest 
/home/davka/workspaces/v1.1-POC/boostfstest/Debug/boostfstest
```

Note that this gives you the full path **including** the executable file name.

Comment: +1 Is it possible to remove executable filename and keep only path to folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273691/using-progname-instead-of-argv0/273701#273701

Comment: @Blender: check out the `parent_path()` method of the `path` class. My boost version is old so I don't have it to try

Comment: Restoring parity, I can't see what's wrong with this either...@Blender, save it to a `std::string`, do a reverse find for `\\` and a substring to that point - voila.

Comment: @Nim : That's a bit obtuse -- `path` already has a [`parent_path()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-parent_path) member function.

Comment: @ildjarn, ofcourse there is the easy way! :) I completely missed the comment by @davka above mine!!!

Comment: This can fail in several ways since it relies on the search path.

Comment: It won't work if you have `chdir`ed to another directory, and your app was run via a relative path, like `./myapp`.

Comment: You should call `path::canonical` on the resulting path if you wish to get at the original executable location. Otherwise if a symbolic link is used you'll get a path to where that is located.

Comment: This just seems to use the current directory and does not search in the `PATH` environmental variable. So this will only work for local executables, not system ones.

Answer (score 34):

You cannot, Boost.Filesystem does not provide such functionality.

But starting with Boost 1.61 you can use Boost.Dll and function [`boost::dll::program_location`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/dll/program_location.html):

```
#include <boost/dll.hpp>
boost::dll::program_location().parent_path();
```

Comment: This works as expected. The boost::filesystem::current_path() will return the path of the executable. No matter which directory you run it from.

Comment: @munsingh `current_path` returns "current directory", not executable path. If you run a program from the shell from a home folder, that folder will be your current directory, but you executable can be in `/usr/bin/something`. This is the most common way to execute command-line utilities on Unix systems.

Comment: This also will work: 
```boost::dll::program_location().parent_path().parent_path();```

Answer (score 10):

You can't do it reliably with boost::filesystem.

However if you're on windows you can call `GetModuleFileName` to get the complete path of the executable and then use `boost::filesystem` to get the directory. ( see [parent_path](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-parent_path))

Answer (score 2):

As discussed more comprehensively [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe), the most reliable way to do that is not through boost::filesystem. Instead, your implementation should take into the consideration the operating system on which the application is running.

However, for a quick implementation without portability concerns, you can check if your argv[0] returns the complete path to executable. If positive, you can do something like:

```
namespace fs=boost::filesystem;

fs::path selfpath=argv[0];

selfpath=selfpath.remove_filename();
```

Answer (score -2):

From C++ 14 you don't need Boost, you can use the filesystem of the standard library you can do that easily:
(I can confirm this works on Windows and Linux as well)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
int main()
{
    fs::path p = argv[0]; // or "C:executable_name.exe";
    std::cout << "Current path is " << fs::current_path() << '\n'
              << "Absolute path for " << p << " is " << fs::absolute(p) << '\n'
          << "System complete path for " << p << " is " << fs::system_complete(p) << '\n';
}
```

Sample copied from the documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/absolute

Comment: The problem is that: 1) this needs access to `argv` array 2) `argv[0]` might be missing (`argc` _can_ be 0) 3) yields invalid result if program found through environment variables 4) the example is incomplete - does not defined `argc`/`argv` and 5) `std::experimental` which is not really the standard library as the answer claims.