# Program name in argv[0]

Tags: objective-c

I read that `argv[0]` holds the program name i.e. the name by which we save the project....
but when I execute the following statement in my objective C command line program

```
const char *proName=argv[0];
```

i see the following in the console:

```
/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testaehcfzilirskhjbifrwresgppvbp/Build/Products/Debug/test
```

here test is the name of my program....
so what does it give...full path or program name?
Thanks

Comment: some related info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273691/using-progname-instead-of-argv0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't depend on `argv[0]` containing something specific. Sometimes you'll get the full path, sometimes only the program name, sometimes something else entirely.

It depends on how the code was invoked.

Answer (score 3):

As you’ve noticed, `argv[0]` can (but doesn’t always) contain the full path of your executable. If you want the file name only, one solution is:

```
#include <libgen.h>

const char *proName = basename(argv[0]);
```

---

As noted by Mat, `argv[0]` is not always reliable — although it should usually be. It depends on what exactly you’re trying to accomplish.

That said, there’s an alternative way of obtaining the name of the executable on Mac OS X:

```
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <libgen.h>

uint32_t bufsize = 0;

// Ask _NSGetExecutablePath() to return the buffer size
// needed to hold the string containing the executable path
_NSGetExecutablePath(NULL, &bufsize);

// Allocate the string buffer and ask _NSGetExecutablePath()
// to fill it with the executable path
char exepath[bufsize];
_NSGetExecutablePath(exepath, &bufsize);

const char *proName = basename(exepath);
```

Comment: `execl("/your/executable", "this will appear in in argv[0]", "arg1", ...);`  will defeat that. Keep it in mind.