# How to check for command line parameters on C++ in UNIX?

Tags: c++, unix, command-line, parameters

How could you error check for command line parameters on C++ in UNIX? For example, if you entered no parameters, how would you print out an error message rather than just getting a segmentation fault?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Care do show us an example where you get segmentation fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (argc<2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "This program requires more parameters\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `argc` is not greater than 1, then user has provided no command line parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("The command had no arguments.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argv[0]` is not always the name of the executed program. If you use `execl` it can be anything, including NULL. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/275317/79455

Comment: Re "The first argument (argv[0]) is always the name of the executed program": That's wrong. It is by convention rather than mandate that `argv[0]` is the name of the program. You can make `argv[0]` whatever you like if you use the `exec` family of functions to invoke some program. There are some strong security reasons not to pass the name (or especially the path) as `argv[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getopt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt).

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend boost `program_option` library for command line parsing.