# How to get the application running path at runtime in c++

Tags: c++, linux

I am running the application by double clicking the file, so getcwd API takes the running path as root directory. But i am running the application from different path. How to get the correct path of running application in linux c++. Please help Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606041/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-a-process-in-unix-linux try searching before posting a question.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273691/using-progname-instead-of-argv0

Comment: So `readlink(2)` the `/proc/self/exe` pseudofile

Comment: Thanks to all. readlink is working to get the application running path